# mail delivered as spam - phpmailer, how to avoid

Tags: php, phpmailer, spam, spam-prevention

I know that in first look many users mark this question as duplicate, but after reading more than 10 question I did not get any satisfactory answer, almost all question has answers having words like "There's not much you can do about it.", "I am not sure", "There is no sure shot trick" etc. that's why I am writing this question, and I think this is very generalized questions and every php developer faces it at least once, ok enough speech :) , now my question is..

I working on a project management application and am using phpmailer to send mail when any task is created or anybody comments on any bug mails are sent to related users, actually instead of sending mails as soon the action happens I have created a 'notifications' table where I actually save all mail data and a cron script then send all mails, here is some part of my cron script.

```
$query = "select * from notifications where  1 ";
    $projects = $obj_basic->get_query_data($query);  

    if(!empty($projects))
    {
        foreach($projects as $data)
        {       
            $message = html_entity_decode($data['content'], ENT_QUOTES);            
            list($ton, $email) =  get_name_email($data['to']);      

            if(!empty($email))
            {
                $query = "select send_notification from users where email='$email' AND send_notification !='1' ";
                $users = $obj_basic->get_query_data($query);
                if(!empty($users))
                {
                    $deleteQuery = "delete from notifications where id ='".$data['id']."'";
                    $obj_basic->run_query($deleteQuery, 'DELETE');
                    continue;
                }

                $comment_id = $data['reference_id'];
                $attribute = $data['attribute'];
                $mail = new PHPMailer();
                list($fromName, $fromEmail) =  get_name_email($data['from']);       
                if(!empty($comment_id) && $attribute == 'comment')
                {
                    $fromEmail = 'comment@changewebaddress.com';
                }

                $mail->SetFrom($fromEmail, $fromName);
                $mail->AddReplyTo($fromEmail, $fromName);
                $mail->AddAddress($email, $ton);
                $mail->BouncedTo = $fromEmail;
                $mail->IsHTML(true);                               
                $mail->Subject  = $data['subject'];              
                $mail->Body =  $message;        
                $MessageID = "<".md5($comment_id.'_'.$email).'@changewebaddress.com>';
                $mail->MessageID= $MessageID;

                if($mail->Send()) {         
                    if(!empty($comment_id) && $attribute == 'comment')
                    {
                        $query = "SELECT message_id FROM `project_comments` WHERE `id`='$comment_id'; ";
                        $project_comments = $obj_basic->get_query_data($query, 'SELECT');

                        if(!empty($project_comments))
                        {
                            $project_comments[0]['message_id'] = html_entity_decode(trim($project_comments[0]['message_id'], ","));
                            $query = "UPDATE  `project_comments` SET `message_id`=CONCAT_WS(',',  '".mysql_escape_string($project_comments[0]['message_id'])."', '".mysql_escape_string(html_entity_decode($MessageID))."') WHERE `id`='$comment_id'; ";
                            $obj_basic->run_query($query, 'UPDATE');
                        }                       
                    }                   
                    $deleteQuery = "delete from notifications where id ='".$data['id']."'"; 
                    $obj_basic->run_query($deleteQuery, 'DELETE'); 
                }           
            }
        }
    }
```

as per what I have tested everything look good, since I am using phpmailer it sets required header it also sets 'Return-Path:' and 'Reply-To:' in header.

Is there any exact solution on this issue

Comment: In what sense is it "delivered as spam"?

Comment: Please search for duplicates first, this is a very broad topic despite you use a specific library. Therefore get educated first.

Comment: And no, your question will not become that single-piont that gives a clear answer to this problem now or then. No. Instead, of the ten questions you've found what exactly have you tried show the code of your tries and what exactly did not work for you? You need to outline that if you really want to get this answered.

Comment: That cron script is 100% useless in identifying why your emails are delivered as spam. You said it yourself - your research points to answers that say "not much can be done". I'm not sure how exactly you expect that asking the same question is going to result in a different answer. You should instead research _why_ emails can be marked as spam, and fix your email markup accordingly.

Comment: I think you did not read my question completely, and did not understand my problem. I have checked all question having same problem but did not get any solution..

Comment: The fact that you are using php mailer has absolutely nothing to do with your email getting marked as spam. Now we have got that out of the way, you need to ask yourself what is flagging it as spam and why may that system be deciding your email is spam. The only people who can tell you why your mail gets spammed is the administrators of the system that is flagging it as spam.

Comment: If stack overflow users can't help me it's ok for me.. keep down voting..it dosen't matter me.

Comment: @SubodhGhulaxe I read your question and understand it perfectly; you're asking the same question as everyone else, you've read the same answers, and because they didn't have a solution, you think that by asking the same question again you'll get a different answer. I don't understand your logic, but I do understand your question.

Comment: I don't see any CakePHP code in your question, are you sure you're using CakePHP? Otherwise please remove the CakePHP tag from this question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Make sure all of the required headers are being set.
2. Check to see if there are any additional, optional headers that you should be setting.
3. Sending an HTML/multipart message with mismatched text/HTML sections is frowned upon by some filters.
4. Absolutely any mail that you send programmatically should have either a link or instructions on how to opt out. This is usually only enforced by human-curated blacklists and the abuse department at your ISP.
5. Make sure your SMTP server is not blacklisted or has a poor reputation.
6. Make sure your *web server* does not have a poor reputation. Some scanners include the reputation of every MTA in the chain.
7. Review the content of your messages before sending them. If anything in it could even roughly be construed as trying to sell something to someone, change it.
8. Sacrifice a small animal to the dark gods of email and hope against hope.
9. Check the headers of the messages marked as spam to see if the spam filtering system left any useful information about why it was blocked.
10. Ask the receiving server's admins why the message was blocked.
11. Accept that there is no, and never will be an "exact solution on this issue". Ever.

Comment: regarding step 8. in your experience, have furry, cuddly animals better effect than other animals, like a lizard or a cockroach? :D

Comment: @thaJeztah it's really dependant on which god[s] you're intent on dealing with, if you're unlucky enough to have to deal with Ia'hu or Km'Kaast I hope you're not terribly attached to *all* of your children.

Comment: Also only you bring a sacrifice once, must not mean it will help forever.

Comment: @Sammitch I've had some encounters with the evil powers of G'mail and Live and know that they can be very unpredictable! Thanks for the warning!

Comment: How or where do you check number 6?

Comment: @JasperV http://multirbl.valli.org/, but keep in mind that: 1. Those are just the BLs that allow public access. 2. Many of those are so small as to be inconsequential. 3. Some of those [eg: SORBS, V4BL] are wholly disreputable and are beneath concern.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any exact solution on this issue

Unfortunately not. It is a non-trivial issue with much complexity which prevents exact solutions.

Instead you need to find out for each email that is marked as spam what led to the spam scoring of it and reverse-engineer that then to the part(s) of the software and systems you use - either configuration (improve the configuration and setup) or processing (patch the software you use and re-compile/deploy).

If you want to improve the situation here on this website - you wrote that many existing questions are disappointing - please keep a worklog of that doing and document each case. Put this as an answer here so that future users can benefit from that. That would be not doing the same mistakes as the previous users have been done on site not doing this documentation and hence the information is missing.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer has a lot of good advice in it. Additionally, adding an SPF record to my DNS helped avoid spam filters. Learn more about SPF records:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework

Microsoft has a tool to help create such records:

http://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/safety/content/technologies/senderid/wizard/

Answer (score 1):

I know this already has an accepted answer but this is for others who might have had the same problem like me and ended up here. I had a website and mails send from my website ended up in spam boxes. Even if I tried using phpmailer and adding our companies mail-server as an SMTP.

However this could easily be resolved by sort of white listing the IP address of the website to the send filter of your mail server. How this is done exactly I don't know because the admin of the mail server did this for me(google it I guess).

Doing this means that if the receiving side does a DNS lookup or an IP lookup to your mail server. The mail-server tells the receiving side that it indeed was sent from him or his associating IP addresses and therefor it will not end up in the spambox.

However if you do this there is no need for the phpmailer and the standard mail() function works too.