# Mail goes to spam using phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have one website in which I used PHPMailer function to send the emails to respective users but all the emails goes to spam or junk folder. I have used below code & include class.phpmailer.php file.

========================

```
try {
    $mail->AddAddress($to, $toname);
    $mail->SetFrom($from, $fromname);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $message; 
    $mail->Send();  
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert-success alert text-center'>Request send successfully. Please check your inbox to reset password.</div>";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    $_SESSION['msg']= "<div class='alert-error alert text-center'>".$e->errorMessage()."</div>"; //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $_SESSION['msg']=  "<div class='alert-error alert text-center'>".$e->getMessage()."</div>"; //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
```

============================

Please suggest me solution for the same.

Thanks

Comment: providing SMTP details in your code also prevent mail from going to span

Comment: this might help u - `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988325/everytime-my-mail-goes-to-spam-in-phpmailer` and `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302962/mail-delivered-as-spam-phpmailer-how-to-avoid`

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about GMail it has very good spam classfier and marks it spam on the basis of the source of the mail i.e.from where the request was sent for the mail. For other mail services try changing the content of the message.

Comment: if your website domain is mydomain.com then in From headers make sure to use someone@mydomain.com

Comment: where to add "someone@mydomain.com" in header part & how?

Comment: yeah there must be a from header, fill it with something@yourdomain.com